# How can I get the sourcecode for rand() (C++)?

Tags: c++, random

I'm new to programming.

I want to know exactly what rand() does.

Searching only yields examples on its usage. But none explain each step of how the function generates a random number. They treat rand() as a blackbox.

I want to know what rand() is doing; each step.

**Is there a resource that will allow me to see exactly what rand() does?**
This is all open source stuff isn't it? I'll settle for the disassembly, if there's no source.

I know it returns a random number, but how does it generate that number? I want to see each step.

Thank you.

Comment: What system do you care about?  There are presumably almost as many implementations as there are environments.

Comment: Your compiler may have the runtime library source available.  The implementation can probably be found there.

Comment: rand uses a pseudo-random generator, so reading up on the theory behind PRNGs will be more enlightening than any piece of source code

Comment: [This paper](http://www.cems.uwe.ac.uk/~irjohnso/coursenotes/ufeen8-15-m/p1192-parkmiller.pdf) is a classic, not terribly hard to understand, and it covers the basics, though it is primitive by modern standards.   (But so is `rand()`.)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here are some Google results that may help you out:

- [gcc implementation of rand()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3932978/gcc-implementation-of-rand)
- [How is the rand()/srand() function implemented in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12642610/how-is-the-rand-srand-function-implemented-in-c)
- [implementation of rand()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1167253/implementation-of-rand)

...

- http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.2/libstdc++/api/a01206.html
- http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Pseudo_002dRandom-Numbers.html

Comment: Ok. I'm very new to programming (~3 days!) so I didn't know what to search for.

I found the implementation that I need to study here: http://bioen.okstate.edu/Home/prashm%20-%20keep/prashant/VS.NET%20setup%20files/PROGRAM%20FILES/MICROSOFT%20VISUAL%20STUDIO%20.NET/VC7/CRT/SRC/RAND.C

Comment: @user2071506 Oh well, I googled `GNU libc rand`, literally. It came up with the SO links as well. None of the links were from outside the top ~12 hits. :/

Comment: @sehe `GNU libc rand` is hard. `sourcecode for rand() (C++)` literally copied from the title got me nice results too.

Answer (score 17):

Here is [the current glibc implementation](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=stdlib/rand.c;h=ba3a9e79bf3f0d403f5f1d3f7bb8af46f60e5b1e;hb=HEAD):

```
/* Return a random integer between 0 and RAND_MAX.  */
int
rand (void)
{
  return (int) __random ();
}
```

That's not much help, but `__random` eventually calls [`__random_r`](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=stdlib/random_r.c;h=a393dd3c199b5b08a16f3044f2a3bc21f8e88410;hb=HEAD):

```
/* If we are using the trivial TYPE_0 R.N.G., just do the old linear
   congruential bit.  Otherwise, we do our fancy trinomial stuff, which is the
   same in all the other cases due to all the global variables that have been
   set up.  The basic operation is to add the number at the rear pointer into
   the one at the front pointer.  Then both pointers are advanced to the next
   location cyclically in the table.  The value returned is the sum generated,
   reduced to 31 bits by throwing away the "least random" low bit.
   Note: The code takes advantage of the fact that both the front and
   rear pointers can't wrap on the same call by not testing the rear
   pointer if the front one has wrapped.  Returns a 31-bit random number.  */

int
__random_r (buf, result)
     struct random_data *buf;
     int32_t *result;
{
  int32_t *state;

  if (buf == NULL || result == NULL)
    goto fail;

  state = buf->state;

  if (buf->rand_type == TYPE_0)
    {
      int32_t val = state[0];
      val = ((state[0] * 1103515245) + 12345) & 0x7fffffff;
      state[0] = val;
      *result = val;
    }
  else
    {
      int32_t *fptr = buf->fptr;
      int32_t *rptr = buf->rptr;
      int32_t *end_ptr = buf->end_ptr;
      int32_t val;

      val = *fptr += *rptr;
      /* Chucking least random bit.  */
      *result = (val >> 1) & 0x7fffffff;
      ++fptr;
      if (fptr >= end_ptr)
    {
      fptr = state;
      ++rptr;
    }
      else
    {
      ++rptr;
      if (rptr >= end_ptr)
        rptr = state;
    }
      buf->fptr = fptr;
      buf->rptr = rptr;
    }
  return 0;

 fail:
  __set_errno (EINVAL);
  return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can browse the source code for different implementations of the C standard.

The question has been answered before, you might find what you're looking for at [What common algorithms are used for C's rand()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026327/what-common-algorithms-are-used-for-cs-rand)

That answer provides code for glibc's implementation of rand()

Answer (score 2):

The simplest reasonably good pseudo-random number generators are [Linear Congruential Generators (LCGs)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator).  These are iterations of a formula such as

```
X_{n+1} = (a * X_n  +  c) modulo m
```

The constants a, c, and m are chosen to given unpredictable sequences.  X_0 is the random seed value.  Many other algorithms exists, but this is probably enough to get you going.

Really good pseudo-random number generators are more complex, such as the [Mersenne Twister](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_twister).

Comment: Care to explain the -1?

Answer (score 2):

I guess, [THIS](http://www.mscs.dal.ca/~selinger/random/) is what you are looking for. It contains the detailed explanation of random function, and simple C program to understand the algo.

Edit:

You should check [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3783905/inside-random-function-how-is-it-implemented) as well. A possible duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I believe rand is from the C standard library, not the C++ standard library. There is no one implementation of either library, there are several.

You could go somewhere like [this page](http://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=tree) to view the source code for glibc, the c library used on most Linux distributions. For glibc you'd find it in source files under stdlib such as `rand.c` and `random.c`.

A different implementation, such as uClibc might be easier to read. [Try here](http://git.uclibc.org/uClibc/tree/) under the libc/stdlib folder.

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but although [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026327/what-common-algorithms-are-used-for-cs-rand) points to part of the implementation, I found that there is more to `rand()` used in `stdlib`, which is from `[glibc][2]`. From the [2.32 version](http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/libc/glibc-2.32.tar.gz) obtained from [here](http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/libc/), the `stdlib` folder contains a `random.c` file which explains that a simple linear congruential algorithm is used. The folder also has `rand.c` and `rand_r.c` which can show you more of the source code. `stdlib.h` contained in the same folder will show you the values used for macros like `RAND_MAX`.

> /* An improved random number generation package.  In addition to the
> standard    rand()/srand() like interface, this package also has a
> special state info    interface.  The initstate() routine is called
> with a seed, an array of    bytes, and a count of how many bytes are
> being passed in; this array is    then initialized to contain
> information for random number generation with    that much state
> information.  Good sizes for the amount of state    information are
> 32, 64, 128, and 256 bytes.  The state can be switched by    calling
> the setstate() function with the same array as was initialized    with
> initstate().  By default, the package runs with 128 bytes of state
> information and generates far better random numbers than a linear
> congruential generator.  If the amount of state information is less
> than    32 bytes, a simple linear congruential R.N.G. is used.
> Internally, the    state information is treated as an array of longs;
> the zeroth element of    the array is the type of R.N.G. being used
> (small integer); the remainder    of the array is the state
> information for the R.N.G.  Thus, 32 bytes of    state information
> will give 7 longs worth of state information, which will    allow a
> degree seven polynomial.  (Note: The zeroth word of state
> information also has some other information stored in it; see setstate
> for details).  The random number generation technique is a linear
> feedback    shift register approach, employing trinomials (since there
> are fewer terms    to sum up that way).  In this approach, the least
> significant bit of all    the numbers in the state table will act as a
> linear feedback shift register,    and will have period 2^deg - 1
> (where deg is the degree of the polynomial    being used, assuming
> that the polynomial is irreducible and primitive).    The higher order
> bits will have longer periods, since their values are    also
> influenced by pseudo-random carries out of the lower bits.  The
> total period of the generator is approximately deg*(2**deg - 1); thus
> doubling the amount of state information has a vast influence on the
>
> period of the generator.  Note: The deg*(2**deg - 1) is an
> approximation    only good for large deg, when the period of the shift
> register is the    dominant factor.  With deg equal to seven, the
> period is actually much    longer than the 7*(2**7 - 1) predicted by
> this formula.  */