# How are random numbers generated in C (rand function)?

Tags: c, random

The classic way to generate random numbers in C is:

```
srand(time(NULL));
int rand = rand();
```

I want to know the algorithm behind the pseudorandom number generation. How does the `rand()` function work?

*[rand() behaves differently between macOS and Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64680033/rand-behaves-differently-between-macos-and-linux)* doesn't answer my question. It only answers the fact that implementation of `rand()` maybe different according to systems. I'm looking for how it is generally implemented or about the general category of implementations.

Comment: Implementation dependant, the C standard sets only general requirements -- [source](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/random/rand). One specific implementation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18634079/glibc-rand-function-implementation

Comment: Also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59600866/how-predictable-is-the-result-of-rand-between-individual-systems/59604864#59604864

Comment: C doesn't specify how `rand()` is implemented. There are so many duplicates: [implementation of rand()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1167253/995714), [How can I get the sourcecode for rand()?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18969783/995714), [How is the rand()/srand() function implemented](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12642610/995714), [rand function implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18634079/995714), [Inside random() function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3783905/995714), [What is happening inside the rand() function?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67304833/995714)

Answer (score 1):

`rand()` in C is commonly implemented as a [Linear Congruential Generator (LCG)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator), but there are a lot of [random number generators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_random_number_generators) out there.

Even though it is a classic way of generating random numbers, `rand()` has its limitations and I would suggest this other thread where the flaws of it are addressed
[Why is the use of rand() considered bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52869166/why-is-the-use-of-rand-considered-bad)

Depending on your use case you might want to use other methods of random number generation.

Answer (score 0):

`rand()` is defined in `stdlib.h` and its implementation depends on the libc you are using. That way it is not only OS dependant.

For glibc look here:
[glibc:rand.c](https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/stdlib/rand.c#L27) >
[random.c](https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/stdlib/random.c#L287) >
[glibc:random_r.c](https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/stdlib/random_r.c#L353)

ulibc is easier to read and here: [rand.c](https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/stdlib/rand.c#L27) > [random.c](https://github.com/kraj/uClibc/blob/master/libc/stdlib/random.c#L234) > [rand_r.c](https://github.com/kraj/uClibc/blob/master/libc/stdlib/rand_r.c#L25)

FreeBSD libc is here: [rand.c](https://svnweb.freebsd.org/base/head/lib/libc/stdlib/rand.c?view=markup#l79) > [random.c](https://svnweb.freebsd.org/base/head/lib/libc/stdlib/random.c?view=markup#l215)

dietlibc: [rand.c](https://github.com/ensc/dietlibc/blob/master/lib/rand.c#L5) > [rand_r.c](https://github.com/ensc/dietlibc/blob/master/lib/rand_r.c#L20)

Note, that none of these libraries ever reads from `/dev/[u]random` and the implementation is much more interesting to read and understand. To start a research in this rabbit hole the [char/random.c](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/drivers/char/random.c) from the linux kernel is a good starting point and maybe functions like `arch_get_random_long`.