# How to initialize PRNGs to produce identical output in both Julia and Python?

Tags: python, numpy, random, julia

I have the following Julia code to generate synthetic data.

```
using Statistics
using Random

seed_value = 42
Random.seed!(seed_value)

f(x, t) = 3.2 * (x + 0.2t)

n_meas = 20
X = zeros(n_meas, 2)
X[:, 1] .= 1 * rand(n_meas)
X[:, 2] .= 2 * rand(n_meas)

u_meas = f.(X[:, 1], X[:, 2])
u_meas .+= 0.05 * mean(u_meas) * randn(n_meas)
print(u_meas)
```

What is the correct python code that will generate the same dataset (u_meas) as above?

I tried the code below which did not print out the same results as my Julia code

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(42)
def f(x, t):
    return 3.2 * (x + 0.2 * t)

n_meas = 20
X = np.zeros((n_meas, 2))
X[:, 0] = 1 * np.random.rand(n_meas)
X[:, 1] = 2 * np.random.rand(n_meas)

u_meas = f(X[:, 0], X[:, 1])
u_meas += 0.05 * np.mean(u_meas) * np.random.randn(n_meas)
print("u_meas:")
print(u_meas)
```

Comment: There is no guarantee that the pseudorandom number generators are the same even with the same seed `42`. Options include looking for PRNG libraries between the two languages that make such a guarantee, writing your own PRNG in each language, using a common PRNG (e.g. via web API), calling the PRNG in one language via the other, and saving random number streams to a file to be shared between the two languages.

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't a code translation service. Instead, describe what exactly you're having difficulty with, like what you're trying to do and how the results don't meet your needs. The Julia code can be used for illustration, but there needs to be a description too. For reference see [How should we tag code translation questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/265825/4518341) on Meta. For more tips, see [ask].

Comment: `Stack Overflow isn't a code translation service`? OP did not ask for translation. OP themselves translated the code. However they encountered some problem and asked a question about it.

Comment: Oh, what Matt said didn't even cross my mind. If that's your question, then say that! :) e.g. "How do I get the same random numbers in Python as in Julia?"

Comment: The problem is some times even the best of us do not see the problem. Clearly OP thought since the `seed` is given, random array should be the same.

Comment: I looks like Julia `Random` uses Mersenne Twister, as does the NumPy `RandomState` singleton used by the Python code. If the algorithms are really identical, another option I didn't mention before is that it might be possible to manually set the internal states to be identical, even if setting the seed isn't sufficient. So it is worth leaving this open for such an answer, but I'd suggest that the OP simplify the example to demonstrate that the first random number produced by each stream is not the same. E.g., the NumPy example should end with a call to `np.random.rand()`.

Comment: @MSH re "Stack Overflow isn't a code translation service", yes, I stand by that. At face value, OP's asking for a translation verification — something a translation service would do. They haven't given any specifics about the problem and I don't know Julia so I didn't want to assume what the problem could be. Anyway, the question just needs an [edit] to clarify.

Comment: I've changed the title to be in line what some of you think this question *could* be. the other interpretations would lead to instant closure of the question.

Comment: It should be noted that Julia [switched its default PRNG algorithm to Xoshiro256++ in version 1.7](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1.7/stdlib/Random/#Random.Random).

Comment: this mentions "xoshiro" https://github.com/numpy/bitgenerators and I have no idea what this is https://bashtage.github.io/randomgen/devel/bit_generators/xoshiro256.html

Comment: @PaSTE that just indicates the only solution is to roll your own PRNG in both languages and not try to rely on the built-in ones, given they're subject to sudden changes.

Comment: @MarkRansom or just find libraries implementing th same PRNG in both languages and use that. Or copy / convert the referece impl, xoroshiros or PCG fit in a handful of lines (though you may need to add some masking to account for the leveraging of fixed-length integers as the reference implementations are usually in C).

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to do this is to use the same implementation. You can call python->julia or julia-> python with https://github.com/JuliaPy/PythonCall.jl. The advantage of this over using the `rand` from C is that C's `rand` is pretty terrible (both in quality of random numbers and because doing so would require you to implement all the sampling algorithms yourself.)

Answer (score 1):

Although one answer is to call Python's random number generator from Julia, or Julia's from Python, or the same one (e.g. libc's mediocre `rand()`) from both, none of these are reliable ways to have reproducible data.

Neither Numpy (see [here](https://numpy.org/neps/nep-0019-rng-policy.html)) nor Julia (see [here](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/stdlib/Random/#Reproducibility)) guarantee that random numbers will be reproducible from one version to the next (e.g. the algorithm might be improved).

Instead, if you want reproducible data, the most reliable thing is to simply **generate random numbers once and save them to a file** that you read when you run your program (in any language).

(If for some reason this is not feasible, e.g. the file is too big, then the next best option is to implement your own pseudorandom-number code, or better yet copy a good free/open-source implementation into your code since it's hard to do this well.)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you just want to get the same random sequences on one machine, the quickest solution might be be to rely on `rand` from the C standard library:

```
julia> @ccall srand(42::Int32)::Cint
1

julia> @ccall rand()::Int32
71876166

julia> @ccall rand()::Int32
708592740
```

```py
In [1]: from ctypes import CDLL

In [2]: libc = CDLL("libc.so.6")
   ...: libc.srand(42)
Out[2]: 1

In [3]: libc.rand()
Out[3]: 71876166

In [4]: libc.rand()
Out[4]: 708592740
```

Of course you'd have to write some extra code to turn the resulting 32 bit integers into floats ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13409133/1346276)).  And there's the caveat that this is [not a good random generator](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/q/30479), but whether that's important depends on your intended usage.

Comment: C’s standard [doesn’t define an implementation for `rand`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67520816/2166798), so this approach can’t be counted on for portability.

Comment: Oh, maybe I interpreted the question differently then. I assumed that the OP wanted the same random numbers in Python and Julia _on the same machine_. Where there should be only one implementation of `rand`.

Comment: Perhaps. All I can say is that in my field journals are now pushing to have computer modeling results be reproducible by colleagues anywhere in the world. This means making code available and finding ways to make that code completely portable to provide complete transparency. Others can directly confirm that results haven’t been fudged or cherry-picked.